# Is it policy to move Apple/Mac OS questions to Ask Different?

Tags: discussion, support, osx

If a question is clearly Mac only, not even Terminal/nix-related, is it best to simply move it to Ask Different?

Apologies if this was asked before, a search didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not. OS X (and 9, 8 and older I suppose) are on topic and we overlap with ask different there. IPhone questions are off topic unless there is a computer involved. IPads are tablets and are kinda on topic

So no, unless you're the op, don't flag that sort of thing for migration. If you are, we may migrate depending on the circumstances - though, its always better to ask questions on the site you feel is best in the first place.

Comment: Sure thing. I only brought it up because I saw one that had been migrated this morning - but it was iPhone, not Mac. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: 'tablets are on-topic'. Shouldn't Android tablets be in the Android SE?

Comment: Where did you read Android tablets are on topic, only reason Windows RT is on topic is because it's still a PC.